# multiple function curves in core-plot

Tags: objective-c, core-plot

I'm currently trying to add more than one mathematical function curves. Below is part of my code.

```
// draw all expression curves (in viewDidLoad)
for ( j=0; j<self.expNum; j++ ) {

        [self getDataForPlot1:self.plotIndex]; // get DataForPlot of one selected expression
        [self addCurve:self.plotIndex];
}
```

I'm trying to add all curves after drawing the axes, but it is only the last input curve that is drawn. How can I separate the `dataForPlot` for each function?

```
-(void)getDataForPlot1:(int)index
{
    int i;
    NSString *exp;

    int bound, plotNum;
    double interval;

    bound = 3 * scaleX;
    plotNum = 3 * 60;
    interval = (double)bound / plotNum;

    NSMutableArray *contentArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:2*plotNum];

    for ( i = -plotNum; i < plotNum; i++ ) {
        id x;

        x = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: i * interval];

        // get one expression
            .......

        id y = [exp numberByEvaluatingString]; // get y values from the expression
        [contentArray addObject:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:x, @"x", y, @"y", nil]];
    }
    dataForPlot = contentArray;

}


-(void)addCurve:(int)index {

    CPTScatterPlot *boundLinePlot  = [[CPTScatterPlot alloc] init];
    CPTMutableLineStyle *lineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
    lineStyle.miterLimit        = 1.0f;
    lineStyle.lineWidth         = 3.0f;
    lineStyle.lineColor         = [CPTColor blueColor];
    boundLinePlot.dataLineStyle = lineStyle;
    boundLinePlot.identifier    = @"Blue Plot";
    boundLinePlot.dataSource    = self;

    [graph addPlot:boundLinePlot toPlotSpace:plotSpace];

    boundLinePlot.interpolation = CPTScatterPlotInterpolationCurved;
}
```

Comment: Do you save each dataset separately? It looks like the calculated plot data gets overwritten each time you call `-getDataForPlot1:`. How does the datasource differentiate between the plots so it knows which dataset to provide when asked for data by a plot?

Comment: I've later created more dataForPlot arrays and it worked! Thank you for your comment :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Answering the question based on comments above)

Save a copy of each dataset separately. It looks like the calculated plot data gets overwritten each time you call `-getDataForPlot1:`.

Also, set a unique `identifier` for each plot so the datasource can know which one is requesting data.